# Apple HealthKit health records

Tags: swift, healthkit, hkhealthstore

Can I add Patients health records like lab reports etc. to apple health app using health kit in swift? So far what i understand is that you can only read the health record data but you can not write it from your own health app. So what will I have to do to be able to add data in health section in apple's health app.

I have tried to look on the apple's documentation but there is no way to add health records.

Answer (score 1):

The Health Records feature is read-only from a 3rd party API perspective. This data can only be added as a direct download from supported health systems. See here for more information: https://www.apple.com/healthcare/health-records/

Answer (score -1):

I might be misunderstanding what you want to do, but you want to add data using `HealthKit` right?

Here's a bit of sample code I found for step data.

```
let healthStore = HKHealthStore()

// Request authorization to write step count data
let stepCountType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .stepCount)!
healthStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: [stepCountType]) { (success, error) in
    if success {
        // Create a new HKQuantitySample with the step count data
        let quantity = HKQuantity(unit: HKUnit.count(), doubleValue: 1000)
        let sample = HKQuantitySample(type: stepCountType, quantity: quantity, start: Date(), end: Date())

        // Save the new HKQuantitySample to the Health app
        healthStore.save(sample) { (success, error) in
            if success {
                print("Step count saved to Health app.")
            } else {
                print("Error saving step count to Health app: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    } else {
        print("Error requesting authorization to write step count data: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

More docs at [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/saving_data_to_healthkit).

Comment: Thank you very much but I want to add health records like lab result files allergies etc.